# Symfony2 - Why voters are called even for SuperAdmins

Tags: security, symfony, roles, symfony-security

I noticed that my voters are solicited even for SuperAdmin users.

Is it working as expected ?

If yes, I thought that the philosophy of SuperAdmin is that they systematically have all rights, so that we don't have to give them each permission one by one. In that case why not granting access to all voters ?

Do I always have to put

```php
if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
}
```

in my voters ?

Comment: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN is only a convention, and defined through the role hierarchy. So you have to made the check.

Comment: It is indeed a convention but not only. It is automatically granted to all roles without specifying it in the hierarchy. It even gets his own `isSuperAdmin()` check already implemented.

Comment: nope, it's not hardcoded in the framework. The `isSuperAdmin()` check is provided by the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php#L358), in which this role is "hardcoded".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `IddqdVoter` class, you have a special role called `ROLE_IDDQD`.

This voter adds a special role `ROLE_IDDQD` which effectively bypasses any, and all security checks (including voters).

This is what you're looking for. More : [IDDQD Voter](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/blob/master/Security/Authorization/Voter/IddqdVoter.php)

You can even set an alias for the IDDQD role, so I guess that you can alias the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` to the `ROLE_IDDQD`. If you can't do that, simply grant the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` the `ROLE_IDDQD` and you're ready to go.

In order to use this special role, you'll have to enable it by doing so :

```
#config.yml
jms_security_extra:
    enable_iddqd_attribute: true
```