# Symfony - Understanding super admin

Tags: security, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to understand something about Symfony and the "super admin".

When I use [FOSUser to create a user](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/command_line_tools.md#1-create-a-user) with super admin privileges

```
php app/console fos:user:create adminuser --super-admin
```

I'd firstly like to know what means (from the doc)

> [...]Specifying the --super-admin option will flag the user as a super admin[...]

I imagine it means granting `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` to the user because I don't see any super-admin field in the user table.

Secondly, while (still from the doc)

> A super admin has access to any part of your application

```yml
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, ...]
```

Why do we still need to configure the access hierarchy for it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at FOSUserBundle's code you will find that the [CreateUserCommand](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Command/CreateUserCommand.php#L77) if invoked with the `--super-admin` flag will call the [UserManipulator](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Util/UserManipulator.php#L47) with a boolean argument `$superadmin=true`.

Now the UserManipulator calls the [UserManager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php) who will create a User Object, call it's [`setSuperAdmin()`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php#L468) method and persist the new user afterwards.

The method looks as follows:

```
public function setSuperAdmin($boolean)
{
    if (true === $boolean) {
        $this->addRole(static::ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN);
    } else {
        $this->removeRole(static::ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So answering your first question:

**Yes**, the `--super-admin` flag causes `FOSUserBundle` to create a new user with the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` role.

You still have to include the role hierarchy in your security configuration because the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` role basically doesn't differ from any other role.

It's just a **convention** [provided by the Symfony standard edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/config/security.yml#L7) that users with role `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` should not have any access restrictions.

If you want the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` to bypass all security voters by default - have a look at JMSSecurityExtraBundle's [**`IddqdVoter`**](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/blob/master/Security/Authorization/Voter/IddqdVoter.php) which implements this for the special role `ROLE_IDDQD`. But this has already been suggested in your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060443/symfony2-why-voters-are-called-even-for-superadmins).

Comment: Ok I see, I thought it were only concerning Voters and I forgot Voters are always called. I also thought it were made like in Django, in which superusers automatically have all rights. I can't imagine a situation where we want to hide something from superusers.

Answer (score 1):

By defining the hierarchy, you explicitly grant it the ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH roles (or other custom roles you could have)

If you comment this line, and you try to access with your ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN user to an action with a ROLE_ADMIN check, you will get a not allowed error.

The ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN is just a convention for the name the super administrator role should have, but it does not have privileges by it's own, you have to explicitly grant them to it.

Comment: Did you just copy the convention part of my answer? :)

Comment: Haha, no, we were anwering at the same time :) I think it's just the obvious answer when you understand how roles work in Symfony2. But I pointed about the convention in whole Symfony, not only in FOSUserBundle

Comment: Thank you for this simple answer.